# Horizontal NGX Slider goes crazy up and down without stopping in 2.0.4. version

Tags: angular, npm, slider, ngxs

Hello i am using ngx slider

```
<ngx-slider [(ngModel)]="my_pointsNew" (userChange)="onUserChange($event)" [(value)]="verticalSlider3.my_pointsNew" [options]="verticalSlider3.options"> </ngx-slider>
```

and the slider doesn't stop to move after i try to set a value. It goes up and down without stopping. I see that happens in others too but with no solution. It's really frustrating. Any ideas?

[See here how the slider goes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU3fT.gif)

Comment: Have you find solution to this issue ?